# Prove that $A \otimes_R B \cong (A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)/ H$

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products

I am working on the following problem:

Let $A \in Mod-R$ and $B \in R-Mod$. Prove that $A \otimes_R B \cong (A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)/ H$ where $H=\langle ar\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}b - a\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}rb \rangle$ is the subgroup generated by those elements.

I don't really know how to do this. I tried to prove that $(A \otimes_R B)/ H$ satisfies the universal property of the tensor product but I couldn't do anything with that.

Comment: have you tried computing the kernel of $A\otimes_R B \to A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} B$?

Comment: I tried it. It is easy to prove that $H \subset ker f$ but the other inclusion I can't do.

Comment: @DanielValenzuela Why is such a map defined in general? I don't see why $A \times B \to A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B$, $(a,b) \mapsto a \otimes b$, should be middle-linear, namely, why $ar \otimes b = a \otimes rb$ for any $r \in R$.

Comment: The statement is unclear. I assume that $A$ is supposed to be a right $R$-module, and $B$ to be a left $R$-module. Then, it should be $A \otimes_R B \cong \left(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B\right) / H$, not the other way round. For the proof, use universal properties.

Comment: You are exactly right Darij. I corrected the statement. As I said above I tried to prove that $(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)/H$ satisfies the universal property of tensor products but I didn't arrive at a conclusion.

Comment: @darijgrinber Mind your language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the universal property of $A \otimes_R B$, there is a natural homomorphism $A \otimes_R B \to (A \otimes B)/H$, $a \otimes_R b \mapsto a \otimes b + H$. To go the other way around, note that the universal property of $A \otimes B$ gives us a homomorphism $A \otimes_R B \leftarrow A \otimes B$; this map descends to a homomorphism $A \otimes_R B \leftarrow (A \otimes B)/H$, since $H$ belongs to its kernel, and it is clear that this map is an inverse to the first one.

Comment: Thanks. It appears I had the elements of the proof but couldn't put them together. This is a very nice proof.